# Asp.net button isn't firing at first time after I open file upload control througn javascript

Tags: c#

So I have created a custom file upload control so that I can put custom look to the file upload control.

1. I have taken a `asp:fileupload` control and have set display as none;
2. I have taken a `asp:label` to show the selected file name
3. a html button that opens the file dialog through java script
4. an asp button that uploads the file at server side. Following is the javascript code.
   After I open the file dialog on clicking the html button (#3 above) I select the file. After that when I click the asp button (#4 above) it doesn't get click first time. Its happening only on Internet Explorer, on other browers it works fine.

```
 function executeFileUploadControl() {
     alert("welcome")
     document.getElementById("fuImage").click();

     return false;
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#fuImage').change(function () {
         var filename = $(this).val();
         var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lblfileName.ClientID%>');

         lbl.innerHTML = filename;

     });
 });
```

**Controls**

```
<input ID="fuImage" type="file" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" name="htmlFileUpload"/>
<div style="border:1px solid #000; width:200px; float:left; margin-right:5px;">
    <input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="javascript:executeFileUploadControl();" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" id="lblfileName" Text="No file selected"></asp:Label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"  OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
```

Comment: Am further add controls here

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer?